# Error with travis-c and appcompat v-21

Tags: android, travis-ci

i wnt to set CI with travis-ci with my android project.

Those are my gradles:

top-level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        flatDir{
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.1'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}
```

Project specific:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'
apply from: 'config/quality.gradle'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/com.mobandme.ada_v2.4.4.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.github.pedrovgs:renderers:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.0.1'
    compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.4'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.shamanland:fab:0.0.5'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2"
    compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.7.1'
    compile 'com.snappydb:snappydb-lib:0.5.0'
    compile 'com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:2.24.0'

}

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 113
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('***')
            storePassword '***'
            keyAlias '***'
            keyPassword '***'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    productFlavors {}
}
```

And my travis file

```
    language: java
    jdk: oraclejdk7
    env:
      matrix:
        - ANDROID_SDKS=android-21  ANDROID_TARGET=android-21
    branches:
      only:
        - master
    before_install:
      - chmod +x gradlew
      # Install base Android SDK
      - wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
      - tar xzf android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
      - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
      - export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
      # install android build tools
      - wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21.1.1-linux.zip
      - unzip build-tools_r21.1.1-linux.zip -d $ANDROID_HOME
      - mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/
      - mv $ANDROID_HOME/android-5.0 $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/21.1.1
      - echo yes | android update sdk --filter build-tools-21.1.1 --no-ui --force > /dev/null
      - echo yes | android update sdk --filter tools --no-ui --force > /dev/null
      - echo yes | android update sdk --filter platform-tools --no-ui --force > /dev/null
      - echo yes | android update sdk --filter android-21 --no-ui --force > /dev/null
      - echo yes | android update sdk --filter extra-android-support --no-ui --force > /dev/null
      - echo yes | android update sdk --filter extra-android-m2repository --no-ui --force > /dev/null
      - echo yes | android update sdk --filter extra-google-m2repository --no-ui --force > /dev/null
      - echo yes | android update sdk --filter extra-google-google_play_services --no-ui --force > /dev/null

    script:
      - TERM=dumb ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

This is travis output

```
Using worker: worker-linux-docker-e8480109.prod.travis-ci.com:travis-linux-6
system_info
Build system information
Build language: java
Installing an SSH key from: default repository key
Key fingerprint: c3:f4:e6:fd:0c:b3:83:41:2a:d8:cd:ca:b1:3e:65:ca
git.checkout
1.15s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git@github.com:colymore/firext-android.git colymore/firext-android
Cloning into 'colymore/firext-android'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to the list of known hosts.
remote: Counting objects: 2088, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (909/909), done.
remote: Total 2088 (delta 1137), reused 1840 (delta 912)
Receiving objects: 100% (2088/2088), 5.69 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1137/1137), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd colymore/firext-android
$ git checkout -qf 80a86aee1209b99d40d2b11d08292dba6958dbbd
This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables. See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.
Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export ANDROID_SDKS=android-21
$ export ANDROID_TARGET=android-21
$ jdk_switcher use oraclejdk7
Switching to Oracle JDK7 (java-7-oracle), JAVA_HOME will be set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
$ export TERM=dumb
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_60
before_install.1
0.01s$ chmod +x gradlew
before_install.2
1.19s$ wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
--2014-11-30 13:29:31--  http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 74.125.228.97, 74.125.228.98, 74.125.228.99, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|74.125.228.97|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 140827643 (134M) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: `android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz'
100%[======================================>] 140,827,643  118M/s   in 1.1s    
2014-11-30 13:29:33 (118 MB/s) - `android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz' saved [140827643/140827643]
before_install.3
1.37s$ tar xzf android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
before_install.4
0.00s$ export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
before_install.5
0.00s$ export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
before_install.6
0.38s$ wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21.1.1-linux.zip
--2014-11-30 13:29:34--  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21.1.1-linux.zip
Resolving dl-ssl.google.com (dl-ssl.google.com)... 74.125.22.136, 74.125.22.190, 74.125.22.91, ...
Connecting to dl-ssl.google.com (dl-ssl.google.com)|74.125.22.136|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 32642454 (31M) [application/zip]
Saving to: `build-tools_r21.1.1-linux.zip'
100%[======================================>] 32,642,454   109M/s   in 0.3s    
2014-11-30 13:29:34 (109 MB/s) - `build-tools_r21.1.1-linux.zip' saved [32642454/32642454]
before_install.7
0.71s$ unzip build-tools_r21.1.1-linux.zip -d $ANDROID_HOME
Archive:  build-tools_r21.1.1-linux.zip
   creating: /home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/android-sdk-linux/android-5.0/
  inflating: /home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/android-sdk-linux/android-5.0/NOTICE.txt  

before_install.8
0.01s$ mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/
before_install.9
0.01s$ mv $ANDROID_HOME/android-5.0 $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/21.1.1
before_install.10
3.17s$ echo yes | android update sdk --filter build-tools-21.1.1 --no-ui --force > /dev/null
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-21.1.1'
before_install.11
1.19s$ echo yes | android update sdk --filter tools --no-ui --force > /dev/null
before_install.12
2.30s$ echo yes | android update sdk --filter platform-tools --no-ui --force > /dev/null
before_install.13
7.11s$ echo yes | android update sdk --filter android-21 --no-ui --force > /dev/null
before_install.14
3.12s$ echo yes | android update sdk --filter extra-android-support --no-ui --force > /dev/null
before_install.15
4.00s$ echo yes | android update sdk --filter extra-android-m2repository --no-ui --force > /dev/null
before_install.16
3.19s$ echo yes | android update sdk --filter extra-google-m2repository --no-ui --force > /dev/null
before_install.17
3.89s$ echo yes | android update sdk --filter extra-google-google_play_services --no-ui --force > /dev/null
56.27s$ ./gradlew assemble
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip
[Downloads..]
WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20080701 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING [Project: :Firext] variant.getProcessManifest() is deprecated. Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead.
:Firext:preBuild
:Firext:compileDebugNdk
:Firext:preDebugBuild
:Firext:checkDebugManifest
:Firext:preReleaseBuild
:Firext:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library
:Firext:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72102Library
:Firext:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library
:Firext:prepareComEtsyAndroidGridLibrary104Library
:Firext:prepareComGithubJohnkilAndroidRobototextviewRobototextview210Library
:Firext:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6171Library
:Firext:prepareComShamanlandFab005Library
:Firext:prepareComSnappydbSnappydbLib050Library
:Firext:prepareDebugDependencies
:Firext:compileDebugAidl
:Firext:compileDebugRenderscript
:Firext:generateDebugBuildConfig
:Firext:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:mergeDebugAssets
:Firext:generateDebugResValues
:Firext:generateDebugResources
:Firext:mergeDebugResources
/home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/Firext/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
:Firext:mergeDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Firext:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/Firext/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 28.369 secs
The command "eval ./gradlew assemble" failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20080701 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20080701 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING [Project: :Firext] variant.getProcessManifest() is deprecated. Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead.
:Firext:preBuild
:Firext:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:preDebugBuild
:Firext:checkDebugManifest
:Firext:preReleaseBuild
:Firext:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComEtsyAndroidGridLibrary104Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComGithubJohnkilAndroidRobototextviewRobototextview210Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6171Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComShamanlandFab005Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComSnappydbSnappydbLib050Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareDebugDependencies
:Firext:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:mergeDebugResources
/home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/Firext/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
:Firext:mergeDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Firext:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/Firext/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 11.542 secs
The command "eval ./gradlew assemble" failed. Retrying, 3 of 3.
WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20080701 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20080701 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING [Project: :Firext] variant.getProcessManifest() is deprecated. Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead.
:Firext:preBuild
:Firext:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:preDebugBuild
:Firext:checkDebugManifest
:Firext:preReleaseBuild
:Firext:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComEtsyAndroidGridLibrary104Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComGithubJohnkilAndroidRobototextviewRobototextview210Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6171Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComShamanlandFab005Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareComSnappydbSnappydbLib050Library UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:prepareDebugDependencies
:Firext:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:Firext:mergeDebugResources
/home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/Firext/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
:Firext:mergeDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Firext:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/Firext/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 11.423 secs
The command "eval ./gradlew assemble" failed 3 times.
The command "./gradlew assemble" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
To Top

Tip:
Did you know that you can split a build into several smaller pieces? Learn more
How can we help?
Support Ticket
Live Chat
E-Mail us
Documentation
Running Jobs (0)
There are no jobs
Queue (0)
There are no jobs
```

Comment: Is this working before the appcompat v-21?

Comment: Its the first time i set travis-ci with this.
Because the error logs says something related to appcompat-v21, missing png or somethink like this.

Comment: `/dev/null` seems to me like an issue in installation/update of the  sdk. And `/home/travis/build/colymore/firext-android/Firext/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png` that the resources of the library are not accessible by the app maybe an initialization issue or again due to install.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** VM images already include fixed android-wait-for-emulator script and android SDK tools version 24.0.0 by default solving issues I commented.

**Solution - issue 1: Appcompat v21.0.2**

I suggest you try to update platform-tools before tools.

Tools 23.0.5 requires platform-tools 19+, so i don't think you are updating it.
And appcompat-v7:21.0.2 requires last android-m2repository that requires tools 23.0.5.

**Update:** If I'm right about the issue2, you are using their pre-installed SDK, so you are updating tools correctly because they preinstalled platform-tools v20 but if you solve issue2, your problem will be issue1. I'm not sure about issue 2 because you use language:java, I use language:android. Check the path  and search their SDK tools `echo $PATH`.

**Alternative:** If I'm wrong and your problems persist. I see you include a library that could depen on [android-support-v4 and appcompat-v7](https://github.com/mobandme/ADA-Framework/tree/master/examples/com.mobandme.ada.examples.devfest/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat/libs).

Check dependencies conflicts.

```
  - ./gradlew androidDependencies
  - ./gradlew -q :Firext:dependencies
  - ./gradlew -q :Firext:dependencyInsight --dependency support-v4 --configuration compile
  - ./gradlew -q :Firext:dependencyInsight --dependency appcompat-v7 --configuration compile
```

You need version 21.0.2 from android.m2repository, you can try to exclude them.

```
compile files('libs/com.mobandme.ada_v2.4.4.jar') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

---

**Solution - issue 2: Builds-tools aapt not found**

I read in your log that `build-tools/aapt` *is not found*. You are adding `ANDROID_HOME` to the end of `PATH`, but Travis-ci already did first, so you are using their `tools/android` at usr/local/android-sdk-23.0.2 that includes build-tools v20.0.0 no 21.1.1.

As you are using docker and you can not update tools to 23.0.5 there due to another issue, you can use my work around so you save already installed `platforms` and `system-images` and can use old `tools/android` to update to 23.0.5. You don't need download it using wget:

```
  - echo "WARNING! delete when fixed";     export OLD_SDK=/usr/local/android-sdk-23.0.2
  - cp -R ${OLD_SDK}/tools ${SDK}/tools || echo "SDK tools copy failed."
  - cp -R ${OLD_SDK}/platforms ${SDK}/platforms || echo "SDK platforms copy failed."
  - cp -R ${OLD_SDK}/system-images ${SDK}/system-images || echo "SDK system-images copy failed."
```

or wait they update VM images soon

or change the order, so you use your SDK:

```
  - export ANDROID_HOME=${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}
```

**Suggestion:**

you don't need download build-tools using wget.

I'm currently using [this](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/jobs/42612007) for updates:

```
  - echo "LIST SUGGESTED SDK PACKAGES";    android list sdk -e || true
  - echo "LIST AVAILABLE SDK PACKAGES";    android list sdk -a -e || true
  - echo "UPDATE PACKAGES IF REQUIRED";    echo y | android update sdk -u -t platform-tool,tool,\
                                           extra-android-support,extra-google-google_play_services,\
                                           extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository,\
                                           android-19,sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-19,\
                                           android-18,sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-18,\
                                           android-17,sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-17,\
                                           android-16,sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-16,\
                                           android-15,sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-15 || true
  - echo "UPDATE PACKAGES IF POSSIBLE";    echo y | android update sdk -a -u -t ${BUILD_TOOLS},\
                                           android-20,android-21,${SDK_EXTRA_PKGS:-} || true
  - echo "LIST SDK UPDATES BY FILTERS";    android update sdk -u -n -t platform,system-image,\
                                           add-on,extra || true
```